# Return statement for a string array giving strange result

Tags: java, arrays, string, return, system.out

I am creating a String array and using System.out.println to print the values in the array. All good and works as expected, returning [South Africa, England] but the code won't compile unless I include a return statement, but the return statement just dumps out a load of garbage "[Ljava.lang.String;@85bdf6". Is there any way I can either combine the System.out.println and return statements so they do the same thing, and I just have [South Africa, England] appearing?

```
   public String[] teamsToProgress()
  { 
    Arrays.sort(teams);
    String[] teamsToProgress;
    teamsToProgress = new String[2];
    String team1 = teams[0].getName();
    String team2 = teams[1].getName();
    teamsToProgress[0] = team1;
    teamsToProgress[1] = team2;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teamsToProgress));
    return teamsToProgress;
  }
```

Comment: `the code won't compile unless I include a return statement` - that's usually the case when your method has a return type other than void.

Comment: Do you want the method to return the array to its caller or just print the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the return statement just dumps out a load of garbage "[Ljava.lang.String;@85bdf6"

That's not the return statement, thats what you do with the return value.
Most probably you have used

```
System.out.println(teamsToProgress());
```

instead you should do what you have done in `teamsToProgress()` already.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teamsToProgress()));
```

In the first case you print what's returned by the `toString()` method of the array (some type information and the hash code), in the second case you print the content of the array.

Generally it's a good idea to either remove the `System.out.println(...)` from the `teamsToProgress()` and print the return value instead - or make the return value `void` and in this case find a better name for the method like `void printTeamsToProgress()`, so the intention of the method becomes clearer.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have `String[]` as a return type. Change it to `void` and it will compile just fine. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) what that 'garbage' `[Ljava.lang.String;@85bdf6` means.